# jquery, grab the link href attribute that was last clicked: making a "follow to external link or don't follow"

Tags: jquery, attributes, hyperlink, external, href

I'm making a tiny script that adds a class of "external" to all external links, then when someone click an external link, it shows a div.question-wrapper that has a div.follow and a div.dontfollow in it, it also displays the url of the link you clicked in the div.question-wrapper. the only problem i'm having is copying the href attr of the link clicked to the button div.follow.

jquery:

```
$(".external").click(function() {
    thisurl = $(this).attr('href')
    $("#question-wrapper").fadeIn('normal')
    $("#follow").attr('href', "($(this).attr('href'))")
        return false;   
    $("#dontfollow").click(function() {
        $("#question-wrapper").fadeOut('normal')
    })
    $("#question-wrapper span").html(
        $(this).attr('href'))
        return false;
    })
```

html:

```
<div id="question-wrapper">
    Would you like to continue on to 
    <span id="url">space where link is</span>?
    <div id="follow">CONTINUE</div>
    <div id="dontfollow">STAY HERE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but `div`s cannot have `href`s, so I would use two `a` tags in the `#question-wrapper` making your HTML look like:

```
<div id="question-wrapper">
    Would you like to continue on to 
    <span id="url">space where link is</span><br/>
    <a id="follow">CONTINUE</a><br/>
    <a id="dontfollow" href="#">STAY HERE</a>
</div>
```

Also, if you put the `href` in quotes then it'll display literally, so

```
$("#follow").attr('href', "($(this).attr('href'))");
```

Will make the `#follow` if it is an `A` look like:

```
<a href="($(this).attr('href'))">blah</a>
```

Also, you already created `thisurl` so use it. Also use `var`, since without declaring them variables become global (properties of `window`):

```
$("#follow").attr('href', thiurl);
```

So the entire thing would look like:

```
$(function() {                                            // <== DOC ready

    $("#question-wrapper").hide();                        // Hide the QR to begin

    $("a.external").click(function() {    // Click handler for all external links

        var thisurl = $(this).attr('href'),                            // The url
            $qr = $("#question-wrapper");                               // The QR

        $qr.fadeIn('normal');                                      // Show the QR

        $("#follow").attr('href', thisurl);              // Set the URL of FOLLOW

          // Make #url a working link too
        $("#url").html('<a href="' + thisurl + '">' + thisurl + '</a>');

        $("#dontfollow").click(function() {
            $qr.fadeOut('normal');
            return false;
        });

        return false;
    });
});​
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kHfNe/)