# Grab href with jQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering is there any chance to grab href link with jQuery?

For example, I have these:

```
<li><a href="head.php">Head</a></li>
<li><a href="body.php">Body</a></li>
<li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
```

So I have made with jQuery some animation but I had to preventDefault();
So now on click of any of these `<a>` tags I get my fancy animation and thats it.
For index I was able to make it redirected because it is basically index.php so I have wrote following:

```
$('a#logo').on('click', function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.replace('index.php');
     }, 1100);
});
```

Now since it would be too much to make ID's for every link and to write that with jQuery... it will be just way too much right?

So how can I tell jQuery... hey on click of specified `<a>` delay redirection for 1 second and then continue where you were before (redirect the page to specified href).

I hope you guys can understand me, and I truly hope that this is possible!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery, grab the link href attribute that was last clicked: making a "follow to external link or don't follow"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941612/jquery-grab-the-link-href-attribute-that-was-last-clicked-making-a-follow-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');  
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = href;
  }, 1100);
});
```

Comment: Yes... That is pretty much it.
$(this).attr('href');

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$(this).attr('href');
```

Therefore:

```
$('li a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');  
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = href;
  }, 1100);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically use

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

to get the target.